# How do I create a custom format, formula or VBA code for the below examples?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ip-address, number-formatting

I have a long list of IPs in Excel that are in an invalid format for a certain site. I have to change/retype each one manually in order to upload the file to the site.

How do I create a custom formula, vba, or format code for the following examples?

The IP format on the left needs to be in the format on the right.

Examples:

```
123.45.678.0 - 123.45.679.255   should be -->   123.45.678-679.*
123.45.678.9 - 123.45.678.12  should be -->   123.45.678.9-12
a.b.c.d - a.b.e.f   should be -->   a.b.c-e.*       
a.b.c.d - a.b.c.f   should be -->   a.b.c.d-f
```

QuickAnalysis Autofill/Flashfill is not activating when I complete a few manually. In other words, Excel isn't picking up the pattern or filling in the rest for me.

Comment: formulas are not going to be the answer here.  You will need to write vba to do this.

Comment: Do you really have those dotted letter strings? If so, can there be more than one letter in a segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a function that converts string inputs into your requested format.

It uses the [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function to compare each part of the ip address from the starting and ending range.

```vb
Function ipFormatter(ByVal ipRange As String) As String
    'Skip inputs with no "-"
    If InStr(1, ipRange, "-") = 0 Then
        ipFormatter = ipRange
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'Removing all spaces
    ipRange = Replace(ipRange, " ", "")
    
    'Splitting the ip addresses into arrays of strings
    Dim ipStart() As String, ipEnd() As String
    ipStart = Split(Split(ipRange, "-")(0), ".")
    ipEnd = Split(Split(ipRange, "-")(1), ".")
    
    Dim ipOut() As String
    ReDim ipOut(UBound(ipStart))
    
    Dim i As Long, setRange As Boolean
    For i = LBound(ipStart) To UBound(ipStart)
        If setRange Then
            'After a range
            ipOut(i) = "*"
        ElseIf ipStart(i) = ipEnd(i) Then
            'Exact Match
            ipOut(i) = ipStart(i)
        Else
            'IP Range found
            ipOut(i) = ipStart(i) & "-" & ipEnd(i)
            setRange = True 'All values after this one will be "*"
        End If
    Next i
    
    ipFormatter = Join(ipOut, ".")
End Function
```

Here are examples of how to use the function

```vb
Sub test()
    Const inputstr As String = "123.45.678.0 - 123.45.679.255"
    
    MsgBox ipFormatter(inputstr)
End Sub

Sub example()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sht.Rows(Sht.Rows.Count).Cells(1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        Sht.Cells(i, 2) = ipFormatter(Sht.Cells(i, 1))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you put this into a code module you can also use it as a UDF inside excel formulas. So you could have a column in your excel sheet with the formula `=ipFormatter(A1)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your work here. Processing it all now and will get back to you.

Comment: I'm a beginner and I'm not sure where to put everything and what steps to follow. 1. Open Visual Basic . 2. Insert --> Module? 3. Paste Code in Module? Am I supposed to run anything? Is it supposed to be a macro? I entered the formula next to a column with an IP and it resulted in #NAME? Thank you.

Comment: In your excel workbook, Press `Alt+F11` to open the VB Project Window. Then Press `Ctrl+R` to open the Project Explorer, which should appear as a column on the left side of the window.  Right mouse click inside the Project Explorer and go to `Insert > Module`. Double click on that new module, which should have a name like `Module1`. Copy and paste my function into the main window. Done! No need to run anything. You can use it in your Excel Formulas same as `SUM` or `COUNT`.

Comment: @Lauren Getting #NAME means the function was not located in a public code module, or the typed name did not match any known function name.  I suspect you might have copied and pasted the code into a sheet code module or the workbook's code module. It needs to be located in a module not associated with a sheet or workbook, like the one created when you do `Insert > Module`. Double check that the code is in the correct location.

Comment: Wow this is amazing! Thank you very much for your help! It worked :)